# Magento 2 : Add discount amount to applied discount in cart

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 cart coupon functionality, when i apply coupon first time it apply discount on cart subtotal, but when i apply coupon second time then old discount amount is replaced by new discount amount.

Is there any way where i can add discount amount to applied discount on cart subtotal?

I know the class "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount" apply discount  but i need to fetch amount of applied coupon code.

Please refer "http://www.9pager.com/the-flow-of-cart-price-rules-discount-whole-cart-in-magento-2/" for discount feature flow.

Thanks